# Container-Optimized OS syslog location?

Tags: google-container-os

Where is Container-Optimized OS’s syslog file located? I’m looking for something like `/var/log/syslog`. One reason I need this is to troubleshoot ssh login failures.

Comment: You will need to use journalctl command

Comment: @JohnHanley – Care to be more specific?

Comment: The syslogs are not located anywhere in the file system. They are sent to Stackdriver. If you want to see what is available inside the machine, you can use journalctl or go to Stackdriver and look at the logs.

Comment: `sudo journalctl -ef` shows logs from sshd, it's exactly what I needed. @JohnHanley, if you want to create an answer to this question, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @JohnHanley BTW, I tried to view logs from this instance in Stackdriver, but there are none. I assumed it's because the agent isn't installed, but following the [installation instructions](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation) failed with error, "Unidentifiable or unsupported platform".

Comment: Stackdriver is built into Container OS. https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/release-notes

Comment: Do you have the "Stackdriver Logging API" enabled on the host instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is Container-Optimized OS’s syslog file located?

The logfiles for Container OS are not stored on the operating system. Instead, the logs are sent to Stackdriver. Containers are designed to be destroyed and recreated. Storing logfiles on the container would mean loosing them.

To view the logs that do exist temporarily, as in the latest logs, you can use the program `journalctl` to view them.

Here is a link to an article that introduces `journalctl` and how to use the basic features:

[Use journalctl to View Your System's Logs](https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/how-to-use-journalctl/)

Comment: The "Container OS" mentioned in the OP's question is not the OS that runs on the containers - rather it's the VM's (the machine hosting the containers) OS. While the rest of your answer is technically correct, it might be clearer to readers if this distinction is mentioned as the original question is about the VM's logs, not the container logs.

Comment: @talonx - perhaps you should move your comment to the question. I do not see the confusion in my answer. In reading the question and both answers, nobody is talking about container logs.

Comment: I think the question is clear enough - it is asking about syslog in the VM. I was referring to your statement "The logfiles for Container OS are not stored on the container." - since there is no reference to storing logs in containers as you said, why bring this up at all?

Comment: @talonx - I have changed the wording in my answer. You have a good point.

Answer (score 6):

> Where is Container-Optimized OS’s syslog file located?

Container-Optimized OS uses systemd-journald to manage system logs, instead of any other syslog daemon (such as rsyslog).

You can see the documentation for systemd-journald at here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Journal

And long story short, you can view the logs via running command such as:

```
sudo journalctl
sudo journalctl -u sshd
```

> One reason I need this is to troubleshoot ssh login failures.

If you have trouble establishing any SSH connection at all, running commands won't be a feasible solution. In that case, GCE serial console logs would be the closest tool:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output

> Stackdriver is built into Container OS. cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/release-notes

[Here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/overlays/board-overlays/+/refs/heads/master/overlay-lakitu/app-admin/stackdriver/files/stackdriver-logging.service) is the source code for the Stackdriver Logging on COS. You can start it via:

```
sudo systemctl start stackdriver-logging
```